# The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

i'm trying to execute an EF update in the following manner but continue to receive this error:

*The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.*

```
        using (hydraEntities db = new hydraEntities())
        {
            YouUser = db.youusers.Include("address").Include("entity").Include("youusercontacts.contact").Include("youuserlogins").Include("youusernotes.note").Include("youusernotes.youuser.entity").Where( yu => yu.YOUUserId.Equals(YOUUserId)).First();
        }

            YouUser.entity.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            YouUser.entity.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            YouUser.address.AddressLine1 = txtAddressLine1.Text;
            YouUser.address.AddressLine2 = txtAddressLine2.Text;
            YouUser.address.City = txtCity.Text;
            YouUser.address.State = ddlState.SelectedValue;
            YouUser.address.Zipcode = txtZipcode.Text;

            using (hydraEntities db = new hydraEntities())
            {
                db.youusers.AddObject(YouUser);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(YouUser, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Would greatly appreciate any insight on how I can fix this and execute the statement above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `AddObject` in this scenario. It is for inserting a new entity but you are updating existing one. Use `Attach` instead:

```
using (hydraEntities db = new hydraEntities())
{
    db.youusers.Attach(YouUser);
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(YouUser, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I was adding objects several times at once through different threads. I had to lock the Model Container object when doing this, to make sure only one object would be processed at once.